# Basic SQL Aggregate

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: runner(r_name(Primary key),miles,week_id) and WEEKDAYS (did,         day_of_week).
runner.week_id references Weekdays.did.

How do i find the day of the week with the longest average miles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an inner query that uses GROUPS runners into the day of week. Use order with limit to select to top entry by week_id. Then select the week with that ID:

```
SELECT *
FROM weekdays
WHERE
week_id IN (
  SELECT week_id
  FROM runner
  GROUP BY week_id
  ORDER BY SUM(miles) DESC
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Using a join:

```
SELECT *
FROM weekdays
JOIN runner
ON runner.week_id = weekdays.id
GROUP BY runner.week_id
ORDER BY SUM(runner.miles) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: How do I write this query without subqueries?